# Perl: Syntactical Sugar for Latter Coderef Arguments?

Tags: perl, syntax, programming-languages, lambda, closures

Using sub prototypes, we can define our own subs that look like map or grep. That is, the first coderef argument has shorter syntax than a normal anonymous sub. For example:

```
sub thunked (&) { $_[0] }

my $val = thunked { 2 * 4 };
```

Works great here, since the first argument is the coderef. For latter arguments however, it simple won't parse properly.

I made a `with` sub designed to make writing GTK2 code cleaner. It's meant to look like this (untested since it's hypothetical code):

```
use 5.012;
use warnings;

use Gtk2 '-init';    

sub with ($&) {
    local $_ = $_[0];
    $_[1]->();
    $_;
}

for (Gtk2::Window->new('toplevel')) {
    $_->set_title('Test Application');
    $_->add(with Gtk2::VBox->new {
        my $box = $_;
        $box->add(Gtk2::Button->new("Button $_")) for (1..4);
    });
    $_->show_all;
}
Gtk2->main;
```

It doesn't work because `with` needs to take the block as a first argument for the nice syntax to work. Is there any way to pull it off?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The module [Devel::Declare](https://metacpan.org/module/Devel::Declare) contains tools for extending Perl's syntax in a relatively safe way.

Using Devel::Declare you would create a hook on the `with` token, which will stop the parser when it reaches that word.  From there, you have control over the parser and you can read ahead until you reach a `{` symbol.  At that point, you have what you need to work with, so you rewrite it into valid Perl, and pass it back to the parser.

in the file `With.pm`:

```
package With;
use warnings;
use strict;
use Devel::Declare;

sub import {
    my $caller = caller;
    Devel::Declare->setup_for (
        $caller => {with => {const => \&parser}}
    );
    no strict 'refs';
    *{$caller.'::with'} = sub ($&) {
        $_[1]() for $_[0];
        $_[0]
    }
}

our $prefix = '';
sub get {substr Devel::Declare::get_linestr, length $prefix}
sub set {       Devel::Declare::set_linestr $prefix . $_[0]}

sub parser {
    local $prefix = substr get, 0, length($_[0]) + $_[1];
    my $with = strip_with();
    strip_space();
    set "scalar($with), sub " . get;
}

sub strip_space {
    my $skip = Devel::Declare::toke_skipspace length $prefix;
    set substr get, $skip;
}

sub strip_with {
    strip_space;
    my $with;
    until (get =~ /^\{/) {
        (my $line = get) =~ s/^([^{]+)//;
        $with .= $1;
        set $line;
        strip_space;
    }
    $with =~ s/\s+/ /g;
    $with
}
```

and to use it:

```
use With;

sub Window::add {say "window add: ", $_[1]->str}
sub Window::new {bless [] => 'Window'}
sub Box::new    {bless [] => 'Box'}
sub Box::add    {push @{$_[0]}, @_[1..$#_]}
sub Box::str    {"Box(@{$_[0]})"}
sub Button::new {"Button($_[1])"}

with Window->new {
    $_->add(with Box->new {
        for my $num (1 .. 4) {
            $_->add(Button->new($num))
        }
    })
};
```

Which prints:

```
window add: Box(Button(1) Button(2) Button(3) Button(4))
```

---

A completely different approach would be to skip the `with` keyword altogether and write a routine to generate constructor subroutines:

```
BEGIN {
    for my $name (qw(VBox)) { # and any others you want
        no strict 'refs';
        *$name = sub (&@) {
            use strict;
            my $code = shift;
            my $with = "Gtk2::$name"->new(@_);
            $code->() for $with;
            $with
        }
    }
}
```

and then your code could look like

```
for (Gtk2::Window->new('toplevel')) {
    $_->set_title('Test Application');
    $_->add(VBox {
        my $box = $_;
        $box->add(Gtk2::Button->new("Button $_")) for (1..4);
    });
    $_->show_all;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

One way that you could deal with it is to add a fairly useless keyword:

```
sub perform(&) { $_[0] }

with GTK2::VBox->new, perform { ... }
```

where `perform` is really just a sugarier alternative to `sub`.

Another way is to write a [Devel::Declare](https://metacpan.org/module/Devel%3a%3aDeclare) filter or a [Syntax::Keyword:: plugin](https://metacpan.org/module/syntax) to implement your `with`, as long as you have some way to tell when you're done parsing the `with` argument and ready to start parsing the block — balanced parentheses would do (so would an opening curly brace, but then hashes become a problem). Then you could support something like

```
with (GTK2::VBox->new) { ... }
```

and let the filter rewrite it to something like

```
do {
    local $_ = GTK2::VBox->new;
    do {
        ...;
    };
    $_;
}
```

which, if it works, has the advantage of not actually creating a sub, and thus not interfering with `@_`, `return`, and a few other things. The two layers of `do`-age I think are necessary for being able to install an [EndOfScope](https://metacpan.org/module/B%3a%3aHooks%3a%3aEndOfScope) hook in the proper place.

The obvious disadvantages of this are that it's tricky, it's hairy, and it's a source filter (even if it's a tame one) which means there are problems you have to solve if you want any code using it to be debuggable at all.